# How should I set up WildFly to access (PUT/GET) standalone HornetQ?

Tags: wildfly, hornetq

We are developing a system to access the HornetQ (standalone) queue that runs in a different process from the EJB application that runs on WildFly 21.

What settings does WildFly need in this case?

What settings should I add to WildFly's standalone.xml?

Comment: How come you're using HornetQ? The HornetQ code-base was donated to the Apache ActiveMQ community almost 6 years ago now and lives on as [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/). There hasn't been a release of HornetQ since then.

Comment: How do you plan on consuming messages? Will you be using MDBs or something else?

Comment: Thanks you, Justin.
I was trying to use it as it was being promoted by some people.
Our system uses a method of sending a message from a session bean to another process (& system) via a queue instead of MDB.
Therefore, I would like to run ActiveMQ Artemis (switching from HornetQ) in a separate process (standalone) from Wildfly.

Comment: Who is promoting HornetQ at this point? You didn't indicate how you planned on consuming messages. Also, are you using a JCA-based connection factory to send your messages?

Comment: Thanks Justin.The specifications we are considering are as follows.
1. EJB (Session Bean) appl -> [request queue] -> Other Appl.
2. EJB appl receive wait [response queue].3. Other Appl -> [response queue] -> EJB appl.

Comment: We will use a JCA-based connection factory to send our messages.